# Swift 3 - creating a re-usable class for HTTP calls

Tags: swift, http

bit of a Swift noob here, although experienced in .net

I am trying to create my first app and to make the code as modular and re-usable as possible.  Therefore, I'm trying to create a class that will allow me to make simple HTTP GET requests and return the resulting text, and optionally the JSON if desired.  I've pasted my code below.  The issue I'm getting is that my function is returning before the HTTP call has finished and therefore returning an empty object.  I think I know why this is happening because I'm calling resume on the task which is then executing and waiting for the callback function to be called - but meantime code execution has continued and therefore I'm returning an empty object.  So...what is the recommended approach here, please?  Should I be placing a callback back to a function on my originating view controller, not trying to create a re-usable class in this way, or something else!  I wait with open arms any suggestions ;)

p.s. some of this code may look familiar as a lot of it is from other articles/posts I've read online and then tailored to what I want.

```
class WebController {

    func makeGetCall(strURL:String, returnJSON:Bool) -> WebControllerResponse {

        //declare a var to store our return
        let wcr:WebControllerResponse = WebControllerResponse()

        // Set up the URL request
        guard let url = URL(string: strURL) else {
            wcr.successful = false
            wcr.returnData = "Error: cannot create URL"
            return wcr
        }

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request

        session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                wcr.successful = false
                wcr.returnData = "error calling GET - " + String(describing: error)
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                wcr.successful = false
                wcr.returnData = "Error: did not receive data"
                return
            }

            if (returnJSON == true) {
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let retObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                        wcr.successful = false
                        wcr.returnData = "error trying to convert data to JSON"
                        return
                    }
                wcr.returnJSON = retObj
                wcr.returnData = String(describing: responseData)
                wcr.successful = true
                }
            catch  {
                wcr.successful = false
                wcr.returnData = "error trying to convert data to JSON"
                return
                }
            }
            else {
                // just return raw data
                wcr.returnData = String(describing: responseData)
                wcr.successful = true
                return
            }
        }).resume()

            return wcr
    }
}
```

my response object is quite simple:

```
class WebControllerResponse {

    var successful:Bool = false
    var returnData:String = ""
    var returnJSON:[String:AnyObject]?

    init() {

    }

}
```

Here is updated code based on feedback from @dirtydanee which is erroring:

class CalTest:UIViewController,WebControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var bigText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var urlIn: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func getButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let wc:WebController = WebController()
    wc.delegate = self
    wc.makeGetCall(strURL: urlIn.text!, returnJSON:false)

}


func webController(webController: WebController, didReceiveResponse: WebControllerResponse) {
    bigText.text = didReceiveResponse.returnData
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLSession` `dataTask` is an async API, therefor you need to return the result from the completion block, not after it.

You need to create a delegate from `WebController` to notify the observing class, when you dataTask completion handler has been called.

```
// Create the protocol
protocol WebControllerDelegate: class {
    func webController(webController: WebController, didReceiveResponse: WebControllerResponse)
}

class WebController {

    // Add delegate variable to class
    weak var delegate: WebControllerDelegate?

    // Initaite the call, but do not return anything from the function directly
    func makeGetCall(strURL:String, returnJSON:Bool) {

        //declare a var to store our return
        let wcr:WebControllerResponse = WebControllerResponse()

        // Set up the URL request
        guard let url = URL(string: strURL) else {
            wcr.successful = false
            wcr.returnData = "Error: cannot create URL"
            self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
            return 
        }

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request

        session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                wcr.successful = false
                wcr.returnData = "error calling GET - " + String(describing: error)
                // Add the delegate call to the right places
                self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                wcr.successful = false
                wcr.returnData = "Error: did not receive data"
                return
            }

            if (returnJSON == true) {
                // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
                do {
                    guard let retObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                        wcr.successful = false
                        wcr.returnData = "error trying to convert data to JSON"
                        self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
                        return
                    }
                    wcr.returnJSON = retObj
                    wcr.returnData = String(describing: responseData)
                    wcr.successful = true
                    self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
                }
                catch  {
                    wcr.successful = false
                    wcr.returnData = "error trying to convert data to JSON"
                    self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
                    return
                }
            }
            else {
                // just return raw data
                wcr.returnData = String(describing: responseData)
                wcr.successful = true
                self.delegate?.webController(webController: self, didReceiveResponse: wcr)
                return
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
class Foo: WebControllerDelegate {
   let webController = WebController() 

    func testWebController() {
        // Assign delegate to self
        webController.delegate = self
        webController.makeGetCall(strURL: "whatever your URL should be", returnJSON: true)
    }

    // Declare the delegate
    func webController(webController: WebController, didReceiveResponse: WebControllerResponse) {
```

// Go to main UI thread
   DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            Assign the text to the UITextView
            bigText.text = didReceiveResponse.returnData
  }
        }
    }

Comment: This is brilliant @dirtydanee - however, I have one issue now.  My delegate is being called successfully, and I am trying to set a UITextView contents with the result of the data (just for testing purposes at this stage). However, I am running into an exception: _NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK_

Comment: can u show the code where you run into this issue? I am thinking whatever you do, should be done on the main thread

Comment: thanks @dirtydanee: class CalTest:UIViewController,WebControllerDelegate {
    
    IBOutlet weak var bigText: UITextView!
    IBOutlet var urlIn: UITextField!
    IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
    
    IBAction func getButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let wc:WebController = WebController()
        wc.delegate = self
        wc.makeGetCall(strURL: urlIn.text!, returnJSON:false)
        
    }

    
    func webController(webController: WebController, didReceiveResponse: WebControllerResponse) {
        bigText.text = didReceiveResponse.returnData
    }

Comment: I removed the @ symbols from my outlets and action to trim the size of the post and to avoid them being picked up as users

Comment: edit your question, do not post code as comment pls.

Comment: Legend @dirtydanee! - thank you, now working a treat.  Will need to go and research DispatchQueue now :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the HTTP request happens asynchronously the function will be returned before it has finished.

The easiest way to fix this would be to use a completion block on your function:

```
func makeGetCall(strURL:String, returnJSON:Bool completion: @escaping (WebControllerResponse?) -> Void) {
    // ...
}
```

Then when the HTTP request has finished you can call the completion handler

```
completion(webControllerResponse)
```